# How do I make a random int?

Tags: java, random

So I am trying to make 100 random integers from 1-100 print out. I can make doubles of this but not integers. Please show me how to make this into integers, here is the code.

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    double r = Math.random();
    double in = r * 100;
    System.out.print(in + ", ");
}
```

Please show me what I messed up or if I need to use an alternate technique for this

Comment: Why not just cast `in` to an int?

Comment: Where you messed up? It’s a strong word choice, I definitely wouldn’t say that you messed up. When you multiply a `double` and an `int`, the result is a `double` (others have shown good alternate techniques, I am not repeating).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use ThreadLocalRandom:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100) + ", ");
        }
```

Comment: Why `ThreadLocalRandom` if he isn't working with threads?

Comment: Because it is more optimized, can scale to threads, the default go-to and more intuitive.
Here is a benchmark proving my point:

`Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
Bench.mathRandomGenerator         thrpt   25   564619.824 ±  10167.329  ops/s
Bench.randomRandomGenerator       thrpt   25   221270.075 ±   6309.199  ops/s
Bench.threadLocalRandomGenerator  thrpt   25  3023022.222 ± 135679.678  ops/s`

Comment: I don't see multiple threads being involved in the question.

Comment: There's a lot of things we don't usually see until it is too late. The simple fact that ThreadLocalRandom is faster than Random can give you a good reason to use it. Also, in the book "Effective Java" by Joshua Block, it is written that ThreadLocalRandom should be used instead of Random even for purposes not involving threads, simply because it is faster.

Comment: @DorianGray From the book "Effective Java" chapter 9:

`As of Java 7, you should no longer use Random . For most uses, the random
number generator of choice is now ThreadLocalRandom . It produces higher
quality random numbers, and it’s very fast. On my machine, it is 3.6 times faster
than Random . For fork join pools and parallel streams, use SplittableRandom .`

Comment: That's interesting,  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Random object instead. from java.util package

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: Random is old and should be deprecated. Use ThreadLocalRandom instead.

Comment: ThreadLocalRandom has benefits in a multi threaded app.  If the app is single threaded then just using Random is ok.

Comment: Why `ThreadLocalRandom` and not `SecureRandom`?

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom` is more versatile, has a richer functionality, so certainly also has its advantages in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: @DorianGray `SecureRandom` is good if you don’t want anyone to predict your random numbers. I use it for generating passwords. If unpredictability is not a requirement, there really isn’t any point in ´SecureRandom`. I would also expect it to work more slowly (though generating a 20 char WiFi code is no problem).

Comment: Unfortunately, `ThreadLocalRandom` does not allow one to set the seed.  This is a feature I use quite often in duplicating test data.  The solutions I have seen tend to adapt Random to a multi-thread environment, so the seed can be set.  So until TLR has **all** the features of Random, with its present performance, Random should be left alone.

Answer (score -1):

Import the class java.util.Random
Make the instance of the class Random, i.e., Random rand = new Random()
Invoke one of the following methods of rand object:
nextInt(upperbound) generates random numbers in the range 0 to upperbound-1.
nextFloat() generates a float between 0.0 and 1.0.
nextDouble() generates a double between 0.0 and 1.0

For example if you want to generate a random number between 1 to 100 the the code will be.

```
import java.util.Random;
Random  r = new Random();
Int number = r.nextInt(100);
```

So variable number will be a  random number between 1 to 100

Comment: Generally the answer is fine, but you should edit it to provide some examples how to generate `int` values in the range `[1..100]` using the methods you mentioned.

Comment: Now I have edited my answer

Answer (score -2):

Whats wrong is the statement double in = r * 100;
It must be

```
 int b = (int) (Math.random()*100)%100; //range [0-99]
```

Just add 1 to b if you strictly want b in the range [1-100]

Comment: You don't need to apply the remainder operator.  Just multiply by 100, cast to an `int` and add `1` as required.